# How to add with tuples

Tags: python, algorithm, tuples

I have pseudo-code like this:

```
if( b < a)
   return (1,0)+foo(a-b,b)
```

I want to write it in python. But can python add tuples? What is the best way to code something like that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do you want to do element-wise addition, or to append the tuples? By default python does

```
(1,2)+(3,4) = (1,2,3,4)
```

You could define your own as:

```
def myadd(x,y):
     z = []
     for i in range(len(x)):
         z.append(x[i]+y[i])
     return tuple(z)
```

Also, as @delnan's comment makes it clear, this is better written as

```
def myadd(xs,ys):
     return tuple(x + y for x, y in izip(xs, ys))
```

or even more functionally:

```
myadd = lambda xs,ys: tuple(x + y for x, y in izip(xs, ys))
```

Then do

```
if( b < a) return myadd((1,0),foo(a-b,b))
```

Comment: `tuple(x + y for x, y in izip(xs, ys))`.

Comment: exactly i wanna do something like 'myadd' this is the best way?

Comment: Yes, and delnan's comment is more pithy.

Comment: If the tuples are of different lengths, your `myadd` will silently truncate the longer tuple to the length of the shorter. This may or may not be a problem.

Answer (score 16):

I'd go for

```
>>> map(sum, zip((1, 2), (3, 4)))
[4, 6]
```

or, more naturally:

```
>>> numpy.array((1, 2)) + numpy.array((3, 4))
array([4, 6])
```

Comment: works - but having to import numpy might be overkill for tiny codes.

Answer (score 3):

```
tuple(map(operator.add, a, b))
```

In contrast to the answer by highBandWidth, this approach requires that the tuples be of the same length in Python 2.7 or earlier, instead raising a TypeError. In Python 3, `map` is slightly different, so that the result is a tuple of sums with length equal to the shorter of `a` and `b`.

If you want the truncation behavior in Python 2, you can replace `map` with `itertools.imap`:

```
tuple(itertools.imap(operator.add, a, b))
```

Comment: do dig the style but does require another import.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `+` itself to act this way, you could subclass `tuple` and override the addition:

```
class mytup(tuple):
    def __add__(self, other):
        if len(self) != len(other):
             return NotImplemented # or raise an error, whatever you prefer
         else:
             return mytup(x+y for x,y in izip(self,other))
```

The same goes for `__sub__`, `__mul__`, `__div__`, `__gt__` (elementwise `>`) etc. More information on these special operators can be found e.g. [here (numeric operations)](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) and [here (comparisions)](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__)

You can still append tuples by calling the original tuple addition: `tuple.__add__(a,b)` instead of `a+b`. Or define an `append()` function in the new class to do this.