# Python: Shortest Weighted Path and Least Number of Edges

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

I am using a networkx weighted graph in order to model a transportation network. I am attempting to find the shortest path in terms of the sum of weighted edges. I have used Dijkstra path in order to find this path. My problem occurs when there is a tie in terms of weighted edges. When this occurs I would always like to choose from the set of paths that tied, the path that has the least number of edges. Dijkstra path does not seem to be doing this.

Is there a way to ensure that I can choose the path with the least number of edges from a set of paths that are tied in terms of sum of weighted edges?

Comment: I should have added:

I have also tried to use the all_shortest_paths ; returning all paths that have the least number of edges.... I was thinking that I could return this set of paths and choose the path that has the least sum of weighted edges. However, I cannot figure out how to get the sum of weighted edges of these paths to accompany them.

I get the generator object for the shortest paths (in terms of number of edges).... is there an easy way to display the sum of weighted edges along with the paths?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using floating points for weights, use tuples `(weight, number_of_edges)` with pairwise addition.  The lowest weight path using these new weights will have the lowest weight, and in the case of a tie, be the shortest path.

To define these weights I would make them a subclass of `tuple` with `__add__` redefined.  Then you should be able to use your existing code.

Comment: Im a bit confused on how to get the weights to be tuples....... If I set the weight parameter to a tuple, networkx does not seem to support adding the datatype to obtain the shortest path distance

Comment: @thecornman Use the solution at http://stackoverflow.com/a/15919466/585411 to define tuples that add correctly.  You will need to `from itertools import izip`, and you'd construct weights by passing a tuple in with `mytup((weight, length))`.  Those special tuples should flow through regular python and Do The Right Thing.